# DRM in Android and iOS for play audio/video in offline mode

Tags: android, ios, exoplayer, drm

right now I have an Android and iOS App that downloads audio and video to play it later offline. The problem with this is that it is easy to access the device and extract these files.

I have seen that a way to play audio/video safely is through the use of DRM, but I am not aware of this in the field of mobile applications.

What DRM can you recommend for this in Android/iOS and more or less what would be the process to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The three major DRM's at this time are:

- Google Widevine, typically used for Android and Chrome
- Apple FairPlay for iOS, MacOS
- Microsoft PlayReady for Windows and Edge

In practice Widevine may be used on Chrome on a MAC or even on iOS sometimes, and smart TV's may use all or a combination, so it is not a strict breakdown.

For your case, Widevine on Android is the most obvious choice and will support the highest Widevine level on most devices.

Possibly the best way for you to learn it and try it out is to use the open source Shaka Packager - you can find specific Widevine documentation for that here (at the time of writing): https://shaka-project.github.io/shaka-packager/html/tutorials/widevine.html